# Php - compare two future dates distance from current date

Tags: php, date, time, intervals

I'm trying to change `$showThis` based on whichever date is closest to now. How can I compare the time differences? Currently `$interval1 > $interval2` does not work. I know the difference is being calculated, but I'm not sure how to compare the two.

```
$currentTime = new DateTime("now");
$wednesday = new DateTime('wednesday 10:59pm');
$saturday = new DateTime('saturday 10:59pm');
$interval1 = $currentTime->diff($wednesday);
$interval2 = $currentTime->diff($saturday);

if($interval1 > $interval2){
    $showThis = $saturday->format('D m/d/Y h:i A');
}
if($interval1 < $interval2){
    $showThis = $wednesday->format('D m/d/Y h:i A');
}
```

Comment: DateTime's diff method returns a DateInterval http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getTimestamp` method.

```
$interval1 = $wednesday->getTimestamp() - $currentTime->getTimestamp();
$interval2 = $saturday->getTimestamp() - $currentTime->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the interval into seconds by adding it to 0 date before comparing them:

```
$currentTime = new DateTime("now");
$wednesday = new DateTime('wednesday 10:59pm');
$saturday = new DateTime('saturday 10:59pm');

$interval1 = $currentTime->diff($wednesday);
$interval2 = $currentTime->diff($saturday);

$seconds1 = date_create('@0')->add($interval1)->getTimestamp();
$seconds2 = date_create('@0')->add($interval2)->getTimestamp();

if ($seconds1 > $seconds2){
    $showThis = $saturday->format('D m/d/Y h:i A');
}
else {
    $showThis = $wednesday->format('D m/d/Y h:i A');
}

echo $showThis;
```